# how to pass activities dynamically in intent to navigate b/w activities in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to create a common method in a non-activity class which will navigate from one activity to another activity. My problem is that I am not able to pass activities dynamically as I have my activities in package "com.example.activity" and the method I want to create is in package "com.exmple.commonmethods". Please tell me what should I do to achieve this.

```
public static void intentFinish(Activity a, Activity b) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(a.getApplicationContext(), b.class);
                a.startActivity(intent);
                a.finish();


    }
```

Comment: did you solve you issue ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public static void StartNewActivity(Activity a, Class<? extends Activity> class1) {
    a.startActivity(new Intent(a, class1));
    a.finish();

}
```